# Trying to stop a service with cron

Tags: 11.04, cron, crontab

On my Ubuntu 11.04 server when I try to run

```
 service powernap stop
```

as a cron job with the root user, it fails and gives me this message in syslog

```
 NAS CRON[10853]: (CRON) error (grandchild #10854 failed with exit status 2)
```

and this is emailed to the root users email account

```
 exec: 129: stop: not found
```

I can start and stop the powernap service from the command line so why doesn't it work from cron?

Comment: How do you exactly setup the cron job?

Comment: did you try /usr/sbin/service powernap stop  ? i.e. the full path to service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `/sbin` is not in `$PATH` when starting it from cron. Add a line like

```
PATH = /sbin:$PATH
```

to the crontab file.

Comment: Without spaces around `=`, of course

Comment: In crontab it should work with the spaces (unlike in a sh compatibel shell)

Comment: Thanks Florian, this worked (and I did include the spaces between the =)

Comment: Had the same issue.  Cron was setting PATH to /usr/bin:/bin.  Adding /sbin and /usr/sbin to the path in my script fixed it right up.

Comment: For some reason this did not work for me. I still have to investigate why. $PATH was not evaluated in the expression.
This worked for me: PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm...it's strange that cron is trying to run "stop"...

Try making cron run this instead:

```
sh -c '/usr/sbin/service powernap stop'
```

Comment: `/usr/sbin/service` is a shell script that is trying to run `stop` (which is `sbin/stop`) here.

Comment: @Florian: I didn't know that. Thanks for the information.

Comment: thanks, I'm going to try both these sugestions, even though I have no idea what sh -c is. What does it do?

Comment: This just gave me a different error message  CRON[11394]: (CRON) error (grandchild #11395 failed with exit status 127), but thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I've had exactly this issue, and it would appear that the `$PATH` variable is completely empty when crontab is run, so it's not enough to put `PATH=/usr/sbin;$PATH` at the top of the crontab list.

So, what I did was (since I'm running this crontab as root, so I can turn off the squid proxy):

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
```

and it seems to have worked.